# Resuming several processes with one signal

Tags: c, unix, process, signals

I need help with the implementation of such a problem: I have a 3 child processes and 1 parent process. Child processes are paused by signal SIGSTOP (parent is not). Operator (user) sends to one of these 3 processes a signal(should work for all 3), which has to resume them all(3 children). I am using library signals.h, but the function which is a handler does not work:

```c
void coninue(int sig)
{
    if(pid_parent == getpid())//if parent get signal
    {
        kill(pid3, 25);
        kill(pid2, 25);
        kill(pid1, 25);
    }
    else//if child get signal
        kill(pid_parent, 25);
}
```

I've tried many ways, but no one work. The main problem is that the process which is paused can only pick up signals SIGCONT and SIGKILL (which can not be captured), so i can only use SIGCONT. 
Thanks for any help :)

PS: Works on UNIX

Comment: Put them in a process group and send the signal to the whole group.

Comment: Each of these processes must be able to handle the task of the operator. So when the operator write in terminal:
kill -sig pid1
kill -sig PID2
kill -sig PID3 it have to work: /

Comment: The parent process can't catch signals sent to children. The operator needs to send the signal to the parent, so it can then signal the children.

Comment: I know. So in this case process group won't work. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: No, you need to redesign.